# How to use AFNetworking 2.0+ with old AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

In my project I have `RestKit` and `IDMPhotoBrowser`(using Cocoapods), so there is two versions `AFNetworking` conflict among themselves. Do you have any idea how to use them both in same project?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use 2 libraries with the same classes in the same project. This is what leads to duplicate symbol errors. On the topic of RestKit + AFNetworking this has been brought up a few times. There's another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000024/transition-from-restkit-to-pure-afnetworking-2-0), there's tons of [issues](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/search?q=afnetworking+2&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) but it sounds like they want to remove AFNetworking as a dependency entirely (from [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/2204#issuecomment-94597307)).